# Does $|x-1|<\delta\implies |f(x)-4|<\epsilon$ and so $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$ exists?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose that for any $\epsilon>0$ the solution to $|f(x)-4|<\epsilon$ is
$$x\in\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{2},1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right).$$
Can we conclude from this that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ exists? It is clear that we need to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit, where in this case the claim is that $\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$. However, I am having trouble understanding that if
$$|x-1|<\delta\implies |f(x)-4|<\epsilon$$
the limit does/does not exit. In general, my proofs involve trying to write $|f(x)-4|$ in the form of $|x-1|$ in order to find a satisfactory $\delta$. I am not sure where to start for this question.

Comment: While applying the definition of limits one doesn't solve the inequality $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon $.

Comment: "... the solution to..." The definite article "the" there implies a misunderstanding. Given one solution, there are always more. S9 it should be "... a solution to..."

Comment: @ParamanandSingh True. All I meant is that if, for example, we were trying to show that $\lim_{x\to 3} -2x+1=-5$ we see that $|-2x+1+5|=|-2x+6|=2|x-3|$ and so it is clear the if $|x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ then $|-2x+1+5|=2|x+3|<2\times\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$. Hence our $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Comment: I would say your opening sentence is garbled. It reads like you are say "If $|f(x)-4|<\epsilon,$ then $x\in(1-\epsilon/2,1+\epsilon/2).$" In fact, you need the reverse implication: "If $x\in(1-\epsilon/2,1+\epsilon/2)$ **then** $|f(x)-4|<\epsilon.$"

Answer (score 1):

If the assertion is:

> For every $\epsilon>0$ we know that $$x\in\left(1-\frac\epsilon2,1+\frac\epsilon2\right) \implies |f(x)-4|<\epsilon$$

then yes, it is the case that $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ exists and equals $4$. The $\epsilon-\delta$ proof goes as follows. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta:=\frac\epsilon2$. If $|x-1|<\delta$ then $x\in(1-\frac\epsilon2,1+\frac\epsilon2)$ so by the assertion, $|f(x)-4|<\epsilon$.

OTOH, if the assertion is:

> For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x\in\left(1-\frac\epsilon2,1+\frac\epsilon2\right)$ such that $|f(x)-4|<\epsilon$

then no, this is not enough to show that $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ exists and equals $4$. Can you see a counterexample?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but there's one thing I don't completely understand. What is the significance of the limit of $4$ here? For instance, if we know that $|x-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\implies |f(x)-3|<\epsilon$, then does this mean that $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ exists and is equal to $3$? Why is $4$ special?

Comment: @Bell Exactly. If the assertion were that $|x-1|<\frac\epsilon2\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, then you would be able to prove that $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ exists and equals $L$.

Comment: Thanks. What is a counterexample to your second assertion? I cannot find it.

Comment: Hint: If the $x$ guaranteed by the second assertion is always the same $x=1$, and $f(1)=4$, then you have no information about the behavior of $f(x)$ anywhere other than $x=1$.

Comment: Ah I see. So you only have the information for a subset of the interval?

Comment: Yes, for this counterexample you only have information for a single point in the interval. The statement "there exists $x$" gives you at least one $x$, but not necessarily more than one.